# Follow feature is missing in SharePoint 2019 Modern site collections

Tags: sharepoint-server, modern-pages, 2019, follow

Follow button(feature) is missing in the SharePoint 2019 modern pages. If you're on the site you want to follow, click Not following a SharePoint site located on the right-hand side of the menu bar to add it to your list of followed sites.

How to enable the follow button(feature) in the modern page? but it showing on the classic site.

Comment: Is "Following content" site feature is enabled on your site??

Comment: UPA is up and running and "Following content" feature is activated. We can see in the classic site but it is not showing up in the modern site.

Comment: In my case, I tried this way disabled the my site creation and re-enabled it, Now It is showing the "Follow" button/feature in modern sites. Thanks for your interest.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the below post, Please check if the UPA is configured and the "User Profile Service" is up and running on the farm. Also, make sure the Site Feature "Following content" is activated in the site where you don't see the follow option.

[Follow option missing in SharePoint 2019 Modern Team Site](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/ie/en-US/bf15ce5a-72fe-42fa-8ca0-da8e688ba07c/follow-option-missing-in-sharepoint-2019-modern-team-site?forum=SP2019)

**Update as per the comment below.**

If still, the follow button is missing, then disabled the **My Site creation** feature and enable it again.

Comment: We checked the link you mentioned previously, UPA is up and running and "Following content" feature is activated. We can see in the classic site but it is not showing up in the modern site.

Comment: In my case, I tried this way disabled the my site creation and re-enabled it, Now It is showing the "Follow" button/feature in modern sites. Thanks for your interest.

Comment: I have updated the answer based on your comment so It will be helpful to other people,

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I did, switched to Classic mode and clicked Follow, it said we will need to setup something and you will need to come back and Follow again blah blah, clicked OK, waited 2 minutes (needs some time to setup OneDrive etc) and after that you see ("Not Followed" click to Follow) in Modern views as well...simple!